# Haskell Cabal package - can't find Paths_ module

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm working on a Haskell project (Happstack server + Blaze HTML/front-end as main libraries) and I want to add a static data directory.

Looks like you can do so with Cabal using the auto-generated `Path_<package_name>` module. So in my example, the package is called `new-website`, so that module should be called `Paths_new_website`.

[Link to Cabal docs re: a custom package's `Paths_pkgname` module.](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/Cabal/authors.html#paths-module)

From the command line and using `cabal repl`, I am trying to confirm that I'll have access to the `Paths_` module. However, I'm finding that the `Paths_new_website` module isn't being imported by Cabal when running `cabal_repl`.

[Here's a link to some relevant code and terminal output via a gist.](https://gist.github.com/mecampbellsoup/8832825)

Does anyone have experience with this, getting a finicky Paths_ module to load with my package? I suspect this may be a question of lexical scope between `Main.hs` (the primary source file) versus the context in `cabal_repl`...

Comment: Are you having trouble compiling or loading it into GHCi? Cabal only produces these `Paths_*` modules during the build. (Edit: Oh, just saw it, `cabal repl`)

Comment: @J.Abrahamson thanks man! Turns out, I just needed to do `import Paths_*` (where `*` is the package name in my `.cabal` build file) inside of `Main.hs`. The cabal documentation made it seem like I only needed to add `Paths_*` inside of my `.cabal` file beneath `other-modules` and I would automatically have access to the `Paths_*` module. Not the case! In fact, even without that addition to my `.cabal` file I'm able to import the auto-generated `Paths_*` module into `Main`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson When you say "during the build", it's my understanding that `cabal repl` is executing a build - is that correct?

Answer (score 6):

`Paths_*` modules are only generated by Cabal during builds. If you're running the package using `GHCi` or `cabal repl` then they simply won't exist and your code will fail with "Cannot find module" errors.

There's a sneaky development mode trick, though: just build your own `Paths_*` module and place it in your `haskell-source-dir`. During development, `GHCi` will load that module and you can adjust its exported symbols to make your development environment fly. During build, Cabal will overwrite your module with its own and take into account the final information needed to build the `Paths_*` module.

So in this particular case, just make a file `src/Paths_stackbuilders.hs` and provide it a relative path to the `datadir`.

Comment: You can also do `ghci -idist/build/autogen`

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested, with a handwritten drop-in-fake-module. But `cabal build` used the fake-module and did not overwrite or superseed it (cabal 1.18)

Comment: Why does `cabal repl` compile the `Paths_pkgname.hs` if it's not usable inside the repl?

Comment: If you use `stack build` then do `:set -i.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/autogen` or include it on the command line (or in the .ghci). It would be desirable, if `stack exec ghci` would include this automatically.

Comment: that sneaky development mode trick doesn't work when the package with `Paths_*` is a dependency, unfortunately. The ghci flag isn't available for me either, I use `ob run` from obsidiansystems/obelisk