# How to integrate dependency into existing project in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack

I am currently trying to get started with Haskell because I want to use parts of the code base of [Pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) for a different project. Since I am new to Haskell I need proper IDE features like *code completion* and *jump to definition* **AND** *type information* and *documentation on hover*. I chose VSCode with the [Haskell extension](https://github.com/haskell/vscode-haskell) for the job.
Now comes my problem: Pandoc depends on [pandoc-types](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types) which is an integral part of the code, which I need to understand and modify. But using the `ghc-option` `"$everything": -haddock` (which should be the right way to achieve my goal according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588500/haskell-cabal-package-cant-find-paths-module)) does not seem to give me proper *type information* and *documentation on hover*. Since I copied the entire repo and do not intend to pull or push from the original repos I would like to add the code from `pandoc-types` to the existing Haskell code in the main `pandoc` repo.

So part of what I have tried was downloading `pandoc-types` moving the `.hs` files into the according dir in `pandoc`, adding the modules to the `.cabal` file while removing the `pandoc-<version>` dependency from the `.cabal` file and the `stack.yaml`. But all I got where compatibility errors when building:

```
➜  pandoc git:(master) ✗ stack build

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for citeproc-0.1.0.1:
    pandoc-types-1.17.6 from stack configuration does not match >=1.22 && <1.23  (latest matching version is 1.22)
needed due to pandoc-2.11.0.1 -> citeproc-0.1.0.1

In the dependencies for commonmark-pandoc-0.2.0.1:
    pandoc-types-1.17.6 from stack configuration does not match >=1.21 && <1.23  (latest matching version is 1.22)
needed due to pandoc-2.11.0.1 -> commonmark-pandoc-0.2.0.1

In the dependencies for texmath-0.12.0.3:
    pandoc-types-1.17.6 from stack configuration does not match >=1.20 && <1.23  (latest matching version is 1.22)
needed due to pandoc-2.11.0.1 -> texmath-0.12.0.3

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' in /Users/johannes/.stack/config.yaml to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /Users/johannes/Programmieren/GITGOV/Pandocs/pandoc/stack.yaml:

- pandoc-types-1.22@sha256:15512ce011555ee720820f11cac0598317293406da5812337cbb1550d144e3bd,4071

Plan construction failed.
```

How can I change a repo from a dependency be part of the code base. I have tried a few different things, but nothing seemed to work out. I am not really familiar with `GHC`, `stack` and `cabal` or even Haskell itself for that matter. Or is there another way to get the *type information* and *documentation on hover* working?
Especially as a Haskell beginner I really need this functionality to properly grasp the code base.

**Maybe also relevant:**

Both repos seem to generate `Paths_*.hs` files in the building process. As far as I understand it, they also need to be copied into the `src/` dir like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588500/haskell-cabal-package-cant-find-paths-module).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the tool one uses there are different ways to go about it.

**If `stack` is used:**

Following the accepted answer in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849269/how-to-install-use-a-local-version-of-package-using-stack) allows me to compile the code via `stack build` with `pandoc-types` as a local dependency.

**If `cabal` is used:**

As with the solution above one needs to add the local dependency into the root folder of the repo. Furthermore one should add a reference to the dependencies `cabal` file to the `cabal.project` file in the `packages:` section as follows (which tells cabal to also compile the contents of this folder):

```
packages: pandoc-types/pandoc-types.cabal pandoc.cabal

package pandoc
  flags: +embed_data_files -trypandoc
  ghc-options: -j +RTS -A64m -RTS

source-repository-package
    type: git
    location: https://github.com/jgm/citeproc
    tag: 0.1.0.1
```

Also the dependencies in the `<projectname>.cabal` need the version restrictions removed. So the file is changed from this:

```
library
  build-depends: pandoc-types          >= 1.22     && < 1.23
```

... to this:

```
library
  build-depends: pandoc-types
```

Now my code compiles with `cabal build`.

However one part of my problem remains. When following both approaches the Haskell extension in VSCode still does not properly autocomplete. Using the `stack` approach gives warnings like `A do-notation statement discarded a result of type ...` and errors like `Could not deduce ... arising from a use of ...`. The first warning should actually already be suppressed with the `-fno-warn-unused-do-bind` flag in `ghc-options` within the `pandoc.cabal` file (assuming this is what the extension reads in order to print warnings/errors). So I don't know what is responsible for these errors. They are not present when the repo was downloaded from Hackage during the build process. I will probably need to ask another question on stack overflow regarding this issue.

Anyway since the question in headline is answered, I hope this helps someone at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the complications of trying to unite what has always been split. Why not just keep the pandoc-types source code in a separate (local) library project --which you can also modify and refer to from your main project-- and load it in a separate editor instance with its own context? You can switch between editors where applicable, when browsing through the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not really an option because I also need to edit the code in this (semi-)external repo. Which would mean that I would need to setup a new public repo to host a copy of the code. And then i would need to add this repo copy as a dependency. It does not make the entire setup easier.