# Local dependency causes error messages in Haskell Extension for VSCode

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, cabal, haskell-stack

I am trying to combine the [pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) and the [pandoc-types](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types) repos to be able to change the source code in both while having the advantages of the Haskel Extension for VSCode (*documentation on hover* and *autocomplete*)

I used both approaches described in my own answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64546722/how-to-integrate-dependency-into-existing-project-in-haskell). I am able to successfully compile my code with `pandoc-types` as a local dependency using `cabal build` and `stack build`.

As mentioned in the Link above, in order to add a local dependency to a `stack` project, the following file needs to be changed from this:

```
flags:
  pandoc:
    trypandoc: false
    embed_data_files: true
    static: false
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps:
- pandoc-types-1.22
- texmath-0.12.0.3
- rfc5051-0.2
- haddock-library-1.9.0
- skylighting-0.10.0.3
- skylighting-core-0.10.0.3
- doclayout-0.3
- emojis-0.1
- hslua-1.1.2
- jira-wiki-markup-1.3.2
- HsYAML-0.2.1.0
- HsYAML-aeson-0.2.0.0
- doctemplates-0.8.2
- commonmark-0.1.1
- commonmark-extensions-0.2.0.2
- commonmark-pandoc-0.2.0.1
- git: https://github.com/jgm/citeproc
  commit: 1860f189e9995c1dc27a68893bedfbf8de1ee67f

ghc-options:
   "$locals": -fhide-source-paths -Wno-missing-home-modules
resolver: lts-14.6
nix:
  packages: [zlib]
```

... to this:

```
flags:
  pandoc:
    trypandoc: false
    embed_data_files: true
    static: false
packages:
- '.'
- pandoc-types
extra-deps:
- texmath-0.12.0.3
- rfc5051-0.2
- haddock-library-1.9.0
- skylighting-0.10.0.2
- skylighting-core-0.10.0.2
- doclayout-0.3
- emojis-0.1
- hslua-1.1.2
- jira-wiki-markup-1.3.2
- HsYAML-0.2.1.0
- HsYAML-aeson-0.2.0.0
- doctemplates-0.8.2
- commonmark-0.1.0.2
- commonmark-extensions-0.2.0.1
- commonmark-pandoc-0.2.0.1
- citeproc-0.1.0.1

ghc-options:
   "$locals": -fhide-source-paths -Wno-missing-home-modules -exclude-module={Paths_pandoc.hs}
resolver: lts-14.6
nix:
  packages: [zlib]
```

But this change results in about 400 warnings of the type `A do-notation statement discarded a result of type <...>` and about 40 errors like `Could not deduce ... arising from a use of ...`. Within the Haskell Extension in VSCode. The first warning should actually already be suppressed with the -fno-warn-unused-do-bind flag in ghc-options within the pandoc.cabal file (assuming this is what the extension reads in order to print warnings/errors). But most importantly the *hover documentation* does not properly work. Compilation still works.

Since I am new to Haskell, and I need to understand the code base, I really require proper IDE features. But I really don't know what the errors/warnings are caused by.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The general setup seems to be correct for my case mentioned in the question.
In order for the Haskell-Language-Server (the base for the extension) to work correctly one needs to setup the [hie-bios](https://github.com/mpickering/hie-bios) using a file named `hie.yaml`.
In my case the file looks like this:

```
cradle:
  stack:
    - path: "./pandoc-types/src"
      component: "pandoc-types:lib"

    - path: "./src"
      component: "pandoc:lib"

    - path: "."
      component: "pandoc:exe:pandoc"
```

The language server properly starts without errors and the local dependency is not downloaded and build in the process.

However I still have not gotten the *hover documentation* to work.